# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Ive started getting this error out of the blue [image: Error]

This only happens when I deploy the application via teamcity. If I run it locally it works fine. 
What ive tried doing .

1. Added the nuget package manually to the class libraries
2. Debug Locally - My local solution runs fine

I have never seen anything like this before.

UPDATE

Ive browsed to my output directory and the DLL Version is this .
This would explain the error but I have no clue why its using this version.

[image: DLL]

UPDATE 2 - As Requested .csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="3.1.66" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Are you targeting the .NET Core runtime or the full framework? If it's the full framework, check for incorrect binding redirects in `app.config`

Comment: .NET core runtime @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: There's no Full .NET Core runtime. There's the Full runtime, currently at 4.7.2 and .NET Core, currently at 2.2.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos excuse me , edited. In any case there are no redirects

Comment: Update the *question* explaining which .NET Core, SignalR, ObjectPool version you use. If possible, post the relevant parts of the `csproj` file. It could be that the TeamCity server doesn't have the correct Core SDK installed though. Or, TeamCity fails to find and deploy all dependencies.

Comment: SignalR version 1.0.4 , Net core 2.0 , object pool 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Im not sure why this happened but on the publish the `Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll` in the publish folder was never being updated .

Simply marking `<DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>` as true in my publish .pubxml and republishing magically fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone in the future.